# Possible to build a dynamic array of streamwriters in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a very large file I need to process (> 10 GB). Hence my use of `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`. My file contains a financial series of market prices in CSV format like this:

`Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close,UpVol,DownVol`

The file contains years of data, and I want to create one file per year, and remove the last two columns. I have a script which does this if I pass in the Year as a parameter. I thought of calling this script multiple times, but it would have to read the very large file multiple times. So, I only want to read the file once, and stream the processed data out to different files dynamically line by line. Here's my Single-Year script:

```
param ( 
    [String]$file=$(throw "Supply a file name to convert"),
    [String]$year
    );

$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file);
$outFile = $file.Substring(0, $file.LastIndexOf('.')) + "-" + $Year + $extension; 

$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($file);
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $outFile;
$reader.ReadLine() > $null                          # skip first line (old header)
$writer.WriteLine("Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close"); # write required header
while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    $data = $line.Split(",");
    if ($data[0] -match $year) {
        $writer.WriteLine($data[0] + "," + $data[1] + "," + $data[2] + "," + $data[3] + "," + $data[4] + "," + $data[5]);
    }
}
$reader.Close();
$writer.Close();
```

So, I'm thinking is it possible to look at $data[0] (the date), find the year with something like this:

`$thisYear = $data[0].Split("/")[2];`

and then dynamically create a `StreamWriter` for each year that's found? Should I create an array of StreamWriters? Snag is, I don't know how many years or which years are in the files before I read them. It has to be done "on the fly". If the file I am reading contains ten years of data, I would expect ten streamwriters to be created with ten extra files at the end with the respective year's data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a hashtable to store them. Then you can just search for the year to find your streamwriter. Try(untested):

```
param ( 
    [String]$file=$(throw "Supply a file name to convert")
    )

$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file) 
$writers = @{}

$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($file)
$reader.ReadLine() > $null                          # skip first line (old header)
while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    $data = $line.Split(",")
    $thisYear = $data[0].Split("/")[2]

    #If new year(no writer available)
    if (!$writers.ContainsKey($thisYear)) {
        #Create writer
        $outFile = $file.Substring(0, $file.LastIndexOf('.')) + "-" + $thisYear + $extension
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $outFile
        $writer.WriteLine("Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close")
        $writers.Add($thisYear, $writer)
    }

    $writers[$thisYear].WriteLine($data[0] + "," + $data[1] + "," + $data[2] + "," + $data[3] + "," + $data[4] + "," + $data[5])
}
$reader.Close()
$writers.GetEnumerator() | % { $_.Value.Close() }
```